# Subversion Commit Big file issue

Tags: centos, svn

I am trying to commit 15mb file in svn. But after 5mb transfer getting error message & commit failed.

Error message is

"svn: Server sent unexpected return value (413 Request Entity Too Large) in response to PUT request for ...."

I tried to use svn commit ,svn import.But no luck.

Any idea regarding same?

Comment: What transport are you using? HTTP?

Comment: transport ? I am using apache httpd

Comment: That setting was not present in my httpd.conf file.So i have added that code in file.As per http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-limiting-upload-size/ site,i have tried to LimitRequestBody 2147483647 for my svn folder..But still not working

Comment: try to commit from command-line and append the following argument `--config-option servers:global:http-library=serf`

Comment: I installed svn on other vps & it worked absolutely fine.Not able to understand issue with the new VPS

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your HTTP server settings to accept bigger requests. As you are using Apache HTTP Server to access your SVN, check your [`LimitRequestBody`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) settings.

Comment: That setting was not present in my httpd.conf file.So i have added that code in file.As per cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-limiting-upload-size site,i have tried to LimitRequestBody 2147483647 for my svn folder..But still not working – user2393759 1 min ago edit

Comment: <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/vps-xyss/sites/ttsosvn">
    LimitRequestBody 2147483647
</Directory> This code i added..